# How to measure bias instability of gyroscope with Allen deviation that has strange end behavior?

Tags: gyroscopes

I have some simulated data from a model of an IMU's gyroscopes. I am trying to use Allan deviation to verify that we have correctly modelled various sources of error in the sensor data. I was able to verify angular random walk, and have now moved on to bias instability.

I'm following a [tutorial on mathworks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fusion/ug/inertial-sensor-noise-analysis-using-allan-variance.html) which describes finding a critical point in the Allan deviation curve, depicted as such:

[image]

However, my sensors do not output this single, easily spotted critical point. My simulated data looks like so:

[image]

Is this normal? If so, are there any techniques to choose the best critical point to get an instability reading? If not, what might cause it?